# JSF 2.0 WebApp not rendering Template

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, facelets

I'm currently working on a JSF 2.0 WebApp, and put my work on a repository in my server. I bought a new computer and checked out the project on it, no problems. It shows no errors. so I'm using the Eclipse IDE Helios. and installed a tomcat v7 server on it. I start it up, no problem. But then when I view my project it's not showing up correctly. it looks like this:

[image]
And the html renders like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/base.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="head">
        <style type="text/css">
            #content{margin:0 10px !important;}
        </style>        
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="sidebar1"></ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">


            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <div class="login">
            <img src="/miloWeb/images/medical.jpg" />
            </div>
            <h:column>
            <center>
                <div class="login">
                    <h4 style="color: #FF0000;"><h:outputText value="#{loginBean.message}"/></h4><br/>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none; width: 265px; text-align: left;" >
                        <li>User ID</li>
                        <li><h:inputText id="userId" styleClass="loginText" value="#{loginBean.user.userID}"></h:inputText></li>
                        <li>Password</li>
                        <li><h:inputSecret id="password" styleClass="loginText" value="#{loginBean.user.password}"></h:inputSecret></li>
                        <li><h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login}" styleClass="button"></h:commandButton></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </center>
            </h:column>
            </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

but if I run it on my original computer ( the one it works in) it should look like this:

[image]

And the html renders like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/miloWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.2"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.2"></script>
            <title>MILO</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/style.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/view.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/ezmark.css" media="screen" />


        <!--[if IE]>
            <style type="text/css"> 
                /* place css fixes for all versions of IE in this conditional comment */
                .milo #content { zoom: 1; }
                /* the above proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout it may need to avoid several bugs */
            </style>
        <![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery.ezmark.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/random.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".button").button();
            });

            function loading(){
                $( "#loadingPopUp" ).dialog( "open" );
                return false;
            }

            function unloading(){
                $( "#loadingPopUp" ).dialog( "close" );
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content{margin:0 10px !important;}
        </style></head><body class="milo">
    <form id="j_idt11" name="j_idt11" method="post" action="/miloWeb/faces/pages/index.xhtml;jsessionid=735F094AD14A3977F9976960A61EEB0C" class="miloForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="j_idt11" value="j_idt11" />

            <div id="container">
                <div id="header"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body>

    <div>
        <h1 class="headerTitle">MILO Chart</h1>
        <div class="headerTreadmark">Medical Information Leading Operations Chart</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="headerInfo"><table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
    </table>

    </div><div id="j_idt11:j_idt42"></div><script id="j_idt11:j_idt42_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('AjaxStatus','widget_j_idt11_j_idt42',{id:'j_idt11:j_idt42'});widget_j_idt11_j_idt42.bindCallback('ajaxStart',function(){loading();});widget_j_idt11_j_idt42.bindCallback('ajaxSuccess',function(){unloading();});</script></body>
</html>
                </div>

                <div id="sidebar1">             
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div id="content"><table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
            <div class="login">
            <img src="/miloWeb/images/medical.jpg" />
            </div></td>
<td>
            <center>
                <div class="login">
                    <h4 style="color: #FF0000;"></h4><br />
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none; width: 265px; text-align: left;">
                        <li>User ID</li>
                        <li><input id="j_idt11:userId" type="text" name="j_idt11:userId" class="loginText" /></li>
                        <li>Password</li>
                        <li><input id="j_idt11:password" type="password" name="j_idt11:password" value="" class="loginText" /></li>
                        <li><input id="j_idt11:login" type="submit" name="j_idt11:login" value="Login" class="button" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </center></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

                </div>

                <br class="clear" />

                <div id="footer"><div id="template_footer_id" style="text-align: center;">&copy; 2012 Bravo Technologies.
</div>
                </div>
            </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="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" autocomplete="off" />
</form></body>

</html>
```

My Images on top are not showing and the input text box are missing and so is the commandbutton. I've checked the files, but they all seem to be there.

It appears that the template Aspect of the App is not working, so thats why the "header" is not showing up and I'm gussing thats why the rest of the attributes are not working as well.

Any and all help is greatly Appreciated. i will be very thankful!

**EDIT: Added web.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>miloWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.bravo.listeners.ServletListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PdfServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bravo.servlets.PdfServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PdfServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PdfServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
       <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
  </filter> 
  <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>
      This is to Have separated faces.config files            
    </description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /pages/history/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/contactInformation/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/childHealthRecord/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/dashboard/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/insurance/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/search/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/labs/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/patient/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/physical/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/notes/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/scheduler/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/settings/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/orderEntry/faces-config.xml,
      /pages/vitals/faces-config.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

AS for the *Tomcatv7.0 Server at localhost* **Startup console:**

The one that works:

```
    Apr 17, 2012 12:24:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6\bin
Apr 17, 2012 12:24:50 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 17, 2012 12:24:50 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Apr 17, 2012 12:24:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 909 ms
Apr 17, 2012 12:24:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 17, 2012 12:24:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.4
Apr 17, 2012 12:24:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor miloWeb.xml from C:\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core is already defined
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://shiro.apache.org/tags is already defined
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:11 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.6 (FCS FCS) for context '/miloWeb'
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeanTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeansScopeTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.calendar.HtmlInputCalendarTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.date.HtmlInputDateTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.schedule.ScheduleTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.HtmlPanelTabbedPaneTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processComponent
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.custom.tree.taglib.TreeTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processValidator
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.validator.ValidatorBaseTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processValidator
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.validator.ValidatorBaseTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processValidator
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.validator.ValidatorBaseTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processValidator
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.apache.myfaces.validator.ValidatorBaseTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor processHandlerClass
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.2
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 24304 ms
```

The one that does NOT work:

```
     Apr 17, 2012 12:25:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:03 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:miloWeb' did not find a matching property.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:03 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:03 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 972 ms
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.4
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core is already defined
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://shiro.apache.org/tags is already defined
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:26 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/miloWeb'
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:26 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:27 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:27 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 23737 ms
```

Comment: This depends pretty much entirely on how the application is implemented, so screenshots aren't much help in figuring out what's wrong.  What troubleshooting measures have you tried?  Are there configuration differences between the old Tomcat and the new one, maybe relating to properties files?  Have you compared the actual HTML being rendered in the two browsers?

Comment: I've checked the tomcat7 configuration, same. jars, same. web.xml, same. but for some reason it doesn't render the same. look at my updated html.

Comment: It seems that for soem reason, the template aspect of the app is not working, so tahts why the header won't show up, and neither will the footer. It's not rendering it... any ideas as to why? or how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: In your web.xml, do you have there any attribute called "servlet" and "servlet-mapping"? how are they configured?

Comment: yes, I have them. I added the web.xml right now. does that look correct?

Comment: okay, that looks correct. can you see any errors on tomcat startup? it looks that tomcat not using jsf :-/

Comment: Added the console messages, as you can see Tobi, the console on the eclipse that works shows much more stuff then the console on the one that doesn't. but no errors...

Comment: say... why do you have /* */ in comments in xml file ? for a test... can you remove all thge commented code that you commented with /* */ ? and why part of the  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> is commented too (and again with /* */)? in xml/html/xhtml you should comment with <!-- some content  -->

Comment: hey Daniel! nice to see you again. It's commented because I believe Stack Overflow's formatting is believing that /* means the begining of a commented section, but in reality It's not commented out.

Comment: ok , another attempt , cvan you remove the /* comments from <style type="text/css"> and any where in the xhtml ? just delete that commented line....

Comment: you mean in the bottom html? that's the rendered html that does work. The rendered HTML that doesn't work is at the top. which has no comments on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the correct Mojarra Version in your tomcat?
It doesn't look so :-/

NOT WORKING:

```
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:26 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/miloWeb'
```

WORKING:

```
Apr 17, 2012 12:25:11 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.6 (FCS FCS) for context '/miloWeb'
```

Comment: I believe this may be the cause, which is weird because teh jars are on the repository. so I need to swith out the jsf-impl.jar and jsf-api.jars in the project tahts not working for the new 2.0 jars correct?

Comment: That did it. nice Catch, tbh I spent about 8 hrs total searching for the answer, it just didn't make sense... the repository had all the jars. I wonder why it didn't update tot he latest ones. Anyway. Thank you so much Tobi. I am super grateful. =D

Comment: Glad to hear, that i could help ;-) anyway... happy coding :-D

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your rendered html it is plain that JSF didn't work on your xhtml. It is as it is. Seems like either the JSF is not configured correctly or the servlet mapping is not correct. You may add you web.xml here and also check whether the JSF is started up correctly from the tomcat logs (in helios console view)

Comment: Added the console messages when i startup the servers on Eclipse. I might have some configuration issue with the tomcat. any idea where I could check?

Comment: as @Tobi found the application is running on JSF 1.2 instead of 2.0. See your eclipse libraries configured for jsf on this project

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will assume it was working and that now without any project changes it isn't?
Then possible problems include:
A server change?
Did you ensure the facelets jar are in your project or in your server?
A name change?
Perhaps your project has a new name or you need to ensure that the project name is mapped correctly in the server?
You corrupted your project?
Did you get any errors when checking in your project or checking it out?

Comment: like I noted, It's working on my original computer, but I've set up a new one and then commited the project to a repository. I've downloaded teh project as it is and the new computer doesn't render the JSf parts. name is the same. and all the jars seem to be there.